# How to pass CORS problem on API identification from Angular7 front?

Tags: api, proxy, cors, angular7, basic-authentication

I am developing a front with Angular 7. 
I need to authenticate to the API with my credentials with a post request.
When I make the request I receive:

```
zone-evergreen.js:2952 OPTIONS https://[...]/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials 400

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://[...]/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://[...]/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials", ok: false, …}
```

I can't change the API, I'd like to know how to fix the CORS problem from angular.

APIservice.ts :

```
const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'})
export class ApicallService {constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient) { }

   createToken() {
         const credentials = { 
          grant_type: 'client_credentials',
          client_id: '***',
          client_secret: '+++',}
        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}) }; 

          return this.httpclient
          .post(API_URL + '/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials', credentials, httpOptions )
            .pipe(map(response => console.log(response))) }
```

My token.component.ts :

```
export class TokenComponent {

   //define a component property called bearer to expose the Bearer array for binding.
  bearer: Bearer[];

   constructor(private http: HttpClient,private callApi: ApicallService) {}

    //call the api by post to identifie
 getBearer(): void{

  this.callApi. createToken() 
        .subscribe();}
```

I also tried to configure a proxy.
My Proxy.conf.json :

```
 {
     "/oauth/*": {
         "target": "http://localhost:4200",
         "secure": false,
         "logLevel": "debug",
         "changeOrigin": true,
         "pathRewrite": {
             "^/oauth": ""
         }
     }}
```

angular.json :

```
 "serve": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
           "options": {
           "browserTarget": "angularjs-wabapp:build",
           "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

Cors is basically on the server to accept any requests coming from any origin.

**You have to change the API to allow cross origin requests** only then this will work.

Comment: I can access to this API with a request in javascript without problem like this, but not in typescript :          //POST to token URL
var request = require("request");

var options = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'https://[...]/oauth/token',
   headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  form: {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_id: '***',
    client_secret: '+++', }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
  console.log(response);
});

Comment: How r u executing the javascript, if it's from same host or not thru http then yes that will not be a prb.

Comment: I execute it by node file.js, with an http post request, what do you mean by same host?

Comment: check this post on CORS for a MEAN app : https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-handle-cors-in-an-angular2-and-node-express-applications-eb3de412abef